# Kafka Connect Hdfs Sink Connector - Class io.confluent.connect.hdfs.string.StringFormat could not be found

Tags: apache-kafka, hdfs, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-connect

Hi i am trying to move csv data from kafka to hdfs using hdfs sink connector and below are the properties i used

Connect.properties

```
name=hdfs-sink
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.hdfs.HdfsSinkConnector
format.class=io.confluent.connect.hdfs.string.StringFormat
tasks.max=1
topics=topic_name
hadoop.conf.dir=/etc/hadoop/conf
hdfs.url=hdfs://nameservice1/dir
flush.size=3
hdfs.authentication.kerberos=true
connect.hdfs.principal=principal
connect.hdfs.keytab=principal.keytab
hdfs.namenode.principal=principal
partitioner.class=io.confluent.connect.hdfs.partitioner.TimeBasedPartitioner
partition.duration.ms=300000
path.format=path.format='year'=YYYY/'month'=MM/'day'=dd
locale=en
timezone=EST
```

worker properties

```
bootstrap.servers=kafkaserver
plugin.path=/opt/confluent/share/java
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
internal.key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
internal.value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
offset.storage.file.filename=/tmp/connect.offsets
internal.key.converter.schemas.enable=false
internal.value.converter.schemas.enable=false
consumer.group.id=connect_group
consumer.auto.offset.reset=earliest
```

and i use confluent-5.0.1

but i get the below exception when i run kafka connect

> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.errors.BadRequestException:
>   Connector configuration is invalid and contains the following 1
>   error(s): Invalid value io.confluent.connect.hdfs.string.StringFormat
>   for configuration format.class: Class
>   io.confluent.connect.hdfs.string.StringFormat could not be found.**
>   You can also find the above list of errors at the endpoint
>   /{connectorType}/config/validate at
>   org.apache.kafka.connect.util.ConvertingFutureCallback.result(ConvertingFutureCallback.java:79)
>   at
>   org.apache.kafka.connect.util.ConvertingFutureCallback.get(ConvertingFutureCallback.java:66)
>   at
>   org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone.main(ConnectStandalone.java:110)
>   Caused by:
>   org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.errors.BadRequestException:
>   Connector configuration is invalid and contains the following 1
>   error(s): Invalid value io.confluent.connect.hdfs.string.StringFormat
>   for configuration format.class: Class
>   io.confluent.connect.hdfs.string.StringFormat could not be found. You
>   can also find the above list of errors at the endpoint
>   /{connectorType}/config/validate at
>   org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.AbstractHerder.maybeAddConfigErrors(AbstractHerder.java:423)
>   at
>   org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.standalone.StandaloneHerder.putConnectorConfig(StandaloneHerder.java:189)
>   at
>   org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone.main(ConnectStandalone.java:107)

Comment: Have you added Sink connector in the plugin path?

Comment: yes it is there. it works for other formats like avro json

Comment: You should be able to use an SMT to convert text line message to say, `{"text": "your data"}`, then write that to JSON or Avro or Parquet, which would be much better from an HDFS Storage perspective. Your `format.class` does **not** need to be the same as your producer data